# Network Congestion Tools

Tags: networking, software-rec, performance, monitoring

Besides Wireshark what are some tools for monitoring network congestion? We are having network issues and want to be absolutely sure it's our ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Orion NetFlow Traffic Analyzer](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/network-traffic-analyzer/) from Solarwinds is a tool that identifies "who & what are consuming your bandwidth". There is a free trial, while the real product starts at €1400.

Solarwinds has an array of excellent network tools.

> Orion NetFlow Traffic Analyzer (NTA) enables you to quantify exactly how your network is being used, by whom, and for what purpose. And our new advanced application mapping feature correlates the traffic arriving from designated ports, source IPs, destination IPs, and even protocols, to application names you can easily recognize. Orion NTA makes it easy to get a comprehensive view of your network traffic, find the bottlenecks, and shut down the bandwidth hogs.

[image]

---

[Snot Network Congestion Monitor Snot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snot/)

Snot is an open source "tool to identify and analyze network congestion."